# Is it possible for a human and another ape species to reproduce?

Tags: human-biology, genetics

Is it possible for a human and another species to reproduce?

Comment: When you say "naturally" I guess you exclude behavior? Because behavior would obviously be one thing that would prevent such mating! Well, let's assume we can find a crazy human and a crazy monkey that would accept doing such thing. The question still holds!

Comment: you are right.I have edited  the question according your comment.thank you

Comment: With our closest relatives, the bonobos/chimpanzees at least, this isn't possible due to differing chromosome counts.

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi is it actually impossible or will it just lead to deformed offspring? Would an egg be fertilized and then die during development or is fertilization itself impossible?

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi: Horses have 64 chromosomes, and donkeys have 62.

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi do you mean that if we find an animal with same chromosome counts then we can have a hybrid of that and human?thank you